# How do I .addClass() when a regex condition is matched, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, regex

I have the following code, see below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var prefixNumber = $('.numeric').val();

   if(prefixNumber.match(????){
      prefixNumber.addClass('.field-error');
   }    

});
```

What I'm looking to happen is when the user types something in the `input.numeric` field and it doesnt match one of these numbers, say...1, 3, 8 or 999 a class `.field-error` is added to the input field which has a red background colour. Kind of trying to make a live error notification if that makes sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a change handler on your input:

```
$('.numeric').change(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('field-error', /[^0-9]/.test(this.value));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a trillion, just what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a couple of numbers, there is no need for regex (especially as they don't have a pattern). You can use an object instead:

```
var valid = {
   1: true,
   3: true,
   8: true,
   999: true
};
```

Then you have to decide when to evaluate the value. If it is while the user is typing, listen to the `keyup` (or `keydown`) event:

```
var timer = null;

function validate() {
     var val = $('.numeric').val()
     $('.numeric').toggleClass('field-error',  val !=='' && !valid[+val]);
}

$('.numeric').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    setTimeout(validate, 400); // time has to be adjusted...
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TrS5p/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

if (!prefixNumber.match(/^\d+$/)) {...}

It forces the prefixNumber to only consist of digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var prefixNumber = $('.numeric');

   if(!prefixNumber.val().match(/^(1|3|8)$/){
      prefixNumber.addClass('field-error');
   }    

});
```

That would display an error if the input isn't 1, 3 or 8 :)

Moved your `val()` method.

Comment: This is only executed on document.ready, and wouldn't update when the user changes the value...

Comment: I was answering the question that the person had, and correcting a problem they were experiencing. They were only asking how to match a RegExp then change class.

Comment: @Michael: You should still provide working code if you provide code.